# Deleting an element from an empty queue?

Tags: c++

I'm writing abstract data type of priority queue as a task for an university, which others are going to use. I have a function in my class dequeue, which deletes the first element in the queue and returns the data of this element. However when I try to delete an element from an empty queue, the program crashes. What should I do here ?

Here's the code if it helps:

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUE_H
#define PRIORITYQUEUE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int max_queue_items = 1000;

template<class T>
struct node{
    T data;
    int priority;
    node *next;
};

template<class T>
class PriorityQueue
{
    public:
        /*
            Constructor that creates an empty queue.
        */
        PriorityQueue(){
            head = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }

        /*
            Adds an element to the queue.

            Params:
            data - data of the element
            priority - priority of the element
        */
        bool is_empty(){
            if (size == 0){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool is_full(){
            if (size == max_queue_items){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        /*
            Adds an element to thq queue.
            It gets inserted before the first element with
            lower priority.
        */
        void enqueue(T data, int priority){
            node<T> * previous = NULL;
            node<T> * now = head;

            while (now != NULL && now->priority >= priority){
                previous = now;
                now = now->next;
            }

            node<T> * new_element = new node<T>;
            new_element->data = data;
            new_element->priority = priority;
            new_element->next = now;

            if (previous == NULL){
                head = new_element;
            } else {
                previous->next = new_element;
            }

            size++;
        }

        /*
            Removes the first element in the queue
        */
        T dequeue(){
            T data;

            if (!is_empty()){
                node<T> * now = head;
                data = now->data;
                head = head->next;
                delete now;

                size--;
            }

            return data;
        }

        /*
            Returns the priority of the first element.
            It's always the highest priority in the queue.
        */
        int get_first_priority(){
            return head->priority;
        }

        /*
            Returns the data of the first element in the queue.
        */
        T get_first_value(){
            if (is_empty())
                throw 0;

            return head->data;
        }

        /*
            Returns the number of elements in the queue.
        */
        int get_size(){
            return size;
        }

        /*
            Deletes the whole queue from the memory.
        */
        void flush(){
            node<T> * now;

            while (head != NULL){
                now = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete now;
                size--;
            }
        }

        /*
            Prints the whole queue following this format:
            data(priority)
        */
        void print(){
            node<T> * now = head;

            while (now != NULL){
                cout << now->data << "(" << now->priority << ")" << endl;
                now = now->next;
            }
        }

    private:
        node<T> * head; // Pointer to the head of the queue
        int size; // Number of elements in the queue
};

#endif // PRIORITYQUEUE_H
```

Comment: You should run it in a debugger to find out which line caused the crash.  If that doesn't allow you to solve the problem, then you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Just a heads up: there is a `std::priority_queue`, and `dequeue` might be a bad name for the function, since `std::deque` is a double ended queue.

Comment: Probably a problem with `is_empty()` implementation.

Comment: @JesseGood is_empty returns true if the size of queue is 0.

Comment: @Marijus: And is `size` equal to `0` when the queue is empty?

Comment: Side note unrelated to your crash: after you finish your class you should look at [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) to see where you fell short.

Comment: @Marijus: We need to see the full code.

Comment: Looking at your code, and running it, I couldn't see anything that could cause a crash. Is it a segfault? Can you show a test-case?

Comment: BTW, I'd check if `head` instead of checking size, it is less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the source of your problem, but I would definitely consider it an issue. In function `dequeue()` you are potentially returning an uninitialized variable (if `T` is not a class type) when `is_empty()` returns `true`:

```
    T dequeue()
    {
        T data; // Uninitialized if T is not a class type

        if (!is_empty())
        {
            node<T> * now = head;

            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            // This initialization is skipped when `is_empty()` returns true
            data = now->data;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------

            head = head->next;
            delete now;

            size--;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Depending on what you do with the value returned by this function and on the type of `T`, your program might have Undefined Behavior (I can imagine `T` being a pointer type that you later dereference).

You may want to change the first line of the function into:

```
T data = T();
```

Which enforces value-initialization of your `data` object. If `T` is a class type, the default constructor will be invoked. Otherwise, `data` will be zero-initialized.

The function which calls `dequeue()` should then check the returned value before using it (or better, call `is_empty()` on the queue to check it is not empty before trying to pop a value from it).

You may even consider throwing an exception when `dequeue()` is invoked and the queue is empty:

```
T dequeue()
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        // Requires including the <stdexcept> standard header
        throw std::logic_error("Queue is empty"); 
    }

    node<T> * now = head;
    T data = now->data;
    head = head->next;
    delete now;

    size--;

    return data;
}
```

Clients are now responsible for making sure that `dequeue()` is never called on an empty queue (or they shall wrap calls to `dequeue()` into a `try/catch` block to handle the possibly thrown exception.

Another possibility is returning a `bool` to your client indicating whether the value was successfully popped, possibly assigning the popped element to an argument passed by reference:

```
bool dequeue(T& data)
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    node<T> * now = head;
    data = now->data;
    head = head->next;
    delete now;

    size--;

    return true;
}
```

This way, the client is responsible for checking the result of the function. If the function returns `false`, the `data` variable will be initialized to whatever the client initialized it to. Responsibilities for handling error situations is again transferred to the client.

Comment: I would like to throw an exception. Could you perhaps give me a short example how to do this with argument passed by reference ?

Comment: this function has to return variable of type T. Is there anything I can do ? I know I could send boolean as an argument and change it if the queue is empty, however I don't really like this solution.

Comment: @Marijus: Then throw an exception

Comment: But what can I do with this exception ? I'm not allowed to print any warnings to the screen and I don't want to pass any arguments to the function, which I could modify using exception. Is there anything else I could do ? Or perhaps use exceptions is some other way I can't think of  ?:

Comment: @Marijus: Maybe you should read a bit about exception handling, it's not something I can explain in a few lines. The problem is simple anyway: what to do when the queue is empty? 1) Return an error code (that's when you return a `bool`); 2) Throw an exception; 3) Return a dummy value (that's what my original answer does, returning a value-inizialied `data`).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues.

First and most important, there is no destructor for the class. And if not all elements are dequeued in your program there will be a memory leak. Write the destructor or use smart pointer instead of the raw one.

Second, as @Andy Prowl(btw who knows how to @ people in post like twitter?) said, uninitialized local variable should be considered. And `T data = T()` works well both for built-in and custom types.

Third, I think there is a capacity restriction `max_queue_items` for the queue but there is no corresponding code for the enqueue part.

Even though, I don't think all these flaws could cause a serious crash in normal case. Maybe the problem occurs in your code invokes the class and the incorrect processing for uninitalized return value leads to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem I see in you dequeue is that you are creating a temporary variable of the unknown type T.  If you are storing data of a type with no default constructor in your priority queue, you are going to have a problem when your dequeue calls and tries to default construct that variable.

If this is the case, I would suggest that you re-work your priority queue to hold pointers to the template type rather than the data itself.